# PHP return variables to AJAX (maybe an array?)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

My wish is to send some information in a datastring through AJAX to a PHP page and then return variables for me to separate and ask jQuery to fill out in different elements. So that it would be able for me to just say:

```
$('.elemA').html($variableA);
$('.elemB').html($variableB); etc.
```

But I am not sure if it is possible or how to do it.. Maybe it can return an array for me to separate somehow? I don't know.

---

If anyone else finds this question - this script helped me out and actually showed me the meaning of the JSON encoding: http://www.jonsuh.com/demo/jquery-ajax-call-to-php-script-with-json-return

Comment: php arrays mean nothing to JS, but you can take a PHP array and json_encode() it, which jquery can take and convert to a javascript array.

Comment: look into jquery ajax. it's very easy to use: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `json_encode($array)`. Which uses [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) to encode your array and return a data string that can be read easily by Javascript.

To convert it to a Javascript array you can use [parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)
or as suggested by @BishopZ use `JSON.parse(ajaxResponse)`, which is built in most modern browsers.

Comment: How do I create a javascript array afterwords? And How do I separate the variables, and use them?

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted, [parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) is there for you.

Comment: In most browsers the Javascript syntax to read the JSON from the ajax response is JSON.parse(ajaxResponse). The JSON object is built into all modern browsers.